# programming database in memory accessible to other programs

Tags: c, shared-memory, mmap

I am currently in the process of writing a network data usage monitor in C (program A) on a 64 bit linux platform.  As a packet sniffer there isn't much time for writing data to a file or db without risking the loss of packets.  I could use another thread for such purposes, but I was thinking that a much cleaner solution (if it exists) would be to access this data stored in memory from another C program or ideally a python cgi script (program B).  That way the data would be available on demand. The data in memory would be accessed read only from Program B. Is this possible?  If so how?  Thanks.

**Updates:**

I see that this is possible with mmap() to store the data in memory, and shmget() to retreive it.  I've heard some say that shmget is old though.  What other options are available?

The 2D arrays to be passed could be as big as 5000x4 int or 5000x15 char.

[posix_ipc](http://semanchuk.com/philip/posix_ipc/) Sounds promising as a way of accessing shared memory from python (program B).  Does anyone know if this will work with shared memory created in C (program A)?

I downloaded [posix_ipc](http://semanchuk.com/philip/posix_ipc/) and it has some really cool demos.  The first one demonstrates two processes talking to each other using shared memory.  The two processes can be any combination of C and python and the source for each of the four are provided.  It looks like the most efficient way to handle what I am trying to do, but I haven't had the time to play with it yet.  I will report back when I do.

che's suggestion below sounds like it will also work, and I will keep that as my plan B.

Thanks to everyone for the help!

Comment: Is there some reason that “old” is a bad thing, here? … i.e. it's widely-available, well-documented, and well-tested …

Comment: @BRPocock, No old isn't bad. It was just describe as "crufty" and "some might say depricated", which didn't sound like a great place to start. It also sounds like it is C only.  Ideally I'd like to be able to access the data read only from a python program B.

Comment: I don't know why it would be seen as “deprecated,” but `mmap` is perhaps a more general-purpose facility. But, yes, bit-twiddling from Python would be difficult. If both processes are in a language with binary-level access like C, though, it's pretty common to use shared memory in this way. Something like `swig` might help bind to Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Shared memory](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node27.html) sounds like the best way to do this between two C programs, especially if the second program will just read the stats written by the first one.

It might be a bit complicated to get to this memory from Python, as it's a bit low-level for this language. The easiest way might be to have a C program that would access the shared memory and print the info in plain text, and call that from your CGI script.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I thought the python part might be tricky. The option you describe, still lacks the ability to retrieve the latest data on demand from a web page via the cgi script.  Is there any other way to do this?  What if program A was also python (using pylibpcap)?

Comment: I would think that running a program that will give you the latest data from shm is on-demand is on-demand enough, where do you see the problem?

Comment: It took me a minute but I see your point.  If I use subprocess in my python cgi script to call the second C program which accesses the shared memory (setup by the first C program) via shmget() and writes this data to a text file.  Then the text file can subsequently be accessed from the cgi script to display the data.

Comment: @nomadicME: Yep. I'd just use standard output/pipe to save myself creating/deleting a file.

Comment: that is even better. :)  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use SQLite, In-Memory mode.  This will give you all the benefits that a database offers, without having a large footprint.

http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't realize that sqlite dbs could exist only in memory.  However, in reading the page you linked, it says: "Of course, all database connections sharing the in-memory database need to be in the same process."  I'm looking for a solution where two separate processes can access the same data stored in memory.  One read-write the other read only. Did I misunderstand the docs?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to posix_ipc: Yes, shared memory regions are “just memory,” they're completely agnostic to the language from which you access them.

However, the way in which you arrange the use of that memory might be limited to the “least common denominator.” An array of fixed-length structures containing fixed-length data fields will be simple and easy, as would certain arrangements of text content; something like “objects with variable fields and garbage-collection” would be difficult to bind between two languages.

For the record, `mmap` is one way to access shared/shareable memory; the `shmget` family of commands (`shmget` and `shmat`, `shmctl` and so forth) are another. Mixing the two would be difficult and not particularly advantageous. (Note that the name `shmget` refers to `get`ting a shared memory region, and doesn't imply read-only access to that memory, necessarily.)

Answer (score 0):

Try memcached if you need simple key/value in-memory storage 
http://memcached.org/

With a plus bonus to learn a technology highly used in web app development as well

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, reading the page you linked to it says this is for small chunks of data. The 2D arrays to be passed could be as big as 5000x4 int or 5000x15 char. I'll update my question with this info.  Also program A needs to be C (ideally) or python.  This sounds like it is only for use in javascript.

Comment: Sorry I didn't read far enough.  You're right this shared memory solution would work between C and python.  My only reservation at this point is the statement that it is for small chunks.  I wonder what small is?  I'll keep reading.  Thanks.

Comment: According to the post provided below, the chunks can be as big as you have free memory available for. I will keep this solution in mind as I proceed.  Thanks. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/memcached/IaMLUeOGxWk

Comment: Read the section "Configurable maximum item size"